# Using ReportingService2010 to Generate PDF report in JAVA usisng SSRS web services

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services, reporting-services

```
ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService2010();
     ReportingService2010Soap reportService = service.getReportingService2010Soap();

    ArrayOfCatalogItem catalogItems=reportService.listChildren("/", true);
    List<CatalogItem> items=catalogItems.getCatalogItem();
    for(CatalogItem catalogItem:items){
        System.out.println(catalogItem.getTypeName()+ " "+ catalogItem.getPath() );         

    }
```

This above are my code in java. I'm successfully able to access the list and i got the output below

```
Folder /Report Project1
```

Report /Report Project1/Report1
DataSource /Report Project1/Test

Now I want to generate Pdf report from the report1 using the Web services class from my java program . If any one know pleased help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a report you have to used ReportExecution2005.asmx web service. For reference on report generation and sample application, please, take a look at MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render(v=sql.105).aspx