# Authentication on java web when call url from SSRS

Tags: java, authentication, ssrs-2012

I want to authentication on java web when call to a url from SSRS, but i don't know how. Please help me

Exp:

URL:http://myServer:port/Reports/report/Test/rpt_sms?P_NUM=something&P_CURR_DT:IsNull=true&rs:Format=PDF

Thank you all

Comment: Show us what you have all ready tried.

Comment: I have read some solution but don't know where i should start: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071830/build-ci-sdlc/a-java-proxy-for-ms-sql-server-reporting-services.html

Comment: I just have found this solution but still find the library in java. Please tell me when someone found something. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562795/using-reportingservice2010-to-generate-pdf-report-in-java-usisng-ssrs-web-servic